# Import/Export sagas,containers,reducers

Tags: reactjs, import, react-redux, export, directory-structure

In my application, I have a folder(Testimonial) whose `index.js` contains below mentioned code snippet.
As I am exporting all sagas, reducers, containers, components in `index.js` and then would like to import them in `app.js`

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as components from './Components';
import * as constants from './constants';
import * as containers from './Containers';
import reducer from './reducers';
import * as sagas from './sagas';

export default {
    actions,
    components, 
    containers,
    constants,
    reducer, 
    sagas
};
```

Now how I can import let's say only containers in my `app.js`, and when I write

```
import Testimonial from './ignitus-Testimonial';
```

This is what the object looks like when I import it and `console.log()` it on my `app.js`

> Testimonail {actions: {…}, components: {…}, containers: {…},
>   constants: {…}, reducer: ƒ, …}

but I only want to make use of `containers` in the `app.js` out of all the exports that I have done.

Comment: a little bit confused now, you said that you stored all of them in the `index.js` file, well then, you `import` them from the `ignitus-Testimonial.js` file. Are `index.js` and `ignitus-Testimonial.js` the same?

Answer (score 1):

If exports are expected to be used separately, they shouldn't be exported as `default` export.

They can be re-exported as:

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as components from './Components';
import * as constants from './constants';
import * as containers from './Containers';
import reducer from './reducers';
import * as sagas from './sagas';

export {
    actions,
    components, 
    containers,
    constants,
    reducer, 
    sagas
};
```

They can be imported separately as:

```
import { sagas } from './ignitus-Testimonial';
```

Or together as:

```
import * as testimonial from './ignitus-Testimonial';
```

The problem with this approach is that it kills tree-shaking optimizations, so it cannot be recommended for uses where output size matters, i.e. client side application.

Answer (score 0):

use named import like below

```
import Testimonial ,{containers} from './ignitus-Testimonial';
```

Comment: No, this is not solving the problem.

Comment: <Testimonial />
is also the component so if I will write ```import {containers} from './ignitus-Testimonial';``` then what about the <Testimonial /> that I am importing.

Comment: on writing ```import {containers} from './ignitus-Testimonial';```  it is returning an Object
actions: {__esModule: true}
components: {__esModule: true}
constants: {__esModule: true}
containers: {__esModule: true}
reducer: ƒ TestimonialReducer()
sagas: {default: ƒ, __esModule: true}
__proto__: Object

Comment: import Testimonial ,{containers} from './ignitus-Testimonial';

Comment: above one will import your<Testimonial /> component along with containers if it is wrong can you share export statement of ignitus-Testimonial.js/jsx

Comment: I have solved it myself :)  writing like this will solve the problem <Testimonial.containers.TestimonialContainer />

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself :) writing like this will solve the problem. `<Testimonial.containers.TestimonialContainer />`